Why is my Timefold optimization not correctly enforcing hard constraints?
I'm working on a Timefold optimization problem where I assign technicians to devices based on constraints like technician skills and capacity. However, the hard constraints (such as technician capacity) are not being enforced correctly. In particular, I notice that some technicians exceed their available work hours (rbh_to_plan) without being penalized, even though I have defined constraints for this in constraints.py.
Here are the key parts of my code:
1. Technician and Device Definitions (domain.py):
@dataclass
class Technician:
    id: int
    name: str
    rbh_to_plan: float
    rbh_assigned: float
    iums: Set[str]
    # Technician class with available hours and skills

@planning_entity
@dataclass
class Device:
    index: int
    ium: str
    technician: Technician | None = field(default=None)
    # Devices assigned to technicians

2. Constraint Definition (constraints.py):
def technician_capacity_hard(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (constraint_factory
            .for_each(Device)
            .filter(lambda device: device.technician is not None)
            .group_by(lambda device: device.technician, ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda device: device.rbh_norm))
            .filter(lambda technician, total_rbh_norm: total_rbh_norm > technician.rbh_to_plan)
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .as_constraint("Technician capacity (hard constraint)"))

3. Main Solver Code (main.py):
solver_factory = SolverFactory.create(
    SolverConfig(
        solution_class=DeviceSchedule,
        entity_class_list=[Device],
        score_director_factory_config=ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig(
            constraint_provider_function=define_constraints  # Enabling constraints
        ),
        termination_config=TerminationConfig(
            best_score_limit="0hard/1000soft",
            spent_limit=Duration(minutes=1)
        )
    )
)

Debugging Steps:

I printed the total assigned hours (rbh_norm) for each technician,
and in many cases, this value exceeds rbh_to_plan.
The HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD is being used to penalize hard constraint
violations, but it seems like it is not being triggered correctly.
My soft constraints, such as rewarding technician assignments, are
working as expected.

Questions:

Why isn't the hard constraint for technician capacity being applied
correctly?
Could there be a problem with how I group and sum the rbh_norm
values in the constraint?
What are the best practices for debugging constraint provider issues
in Timefold?


Is rbh_norm a float? sum should only be used on ints. The domain seems incomplete (no annotations or a sample problem). Consider using decimal.Decimal instead of floats (note: I need to add a sum_decimal collector to use here; as a workaround, change the types to rbh_norm to int (multiplying each by the same power of ten)).

(as for what happened, float will automatically coerce to int when used as a parameter to a function that expects an int, or when used as a return value on a function returning int. The latter case probably happened here, causing lost precision).

Thank you! I didn't realize that sum only works with integers, and some of my rbh_norm values are floats. This explains why sometimes the collector worked fine and other times it didn't. Everything worked properly when my rbh_norm values were integers.


What I suspect happened is rbh_norm is a float, so when it was used as the return value in ConstraintCollector.sum, it was cast to int (losing any value after its decimal point). The one-argument variant of ConstraintCollector.sum expects a function returning int.

The constraint works, provided rbh_norm an int.

ConstraintVerifier is your friend. For example:


from timefold.solver.test import *

constraint_verifier = ConstraintVerifier.build(define_constraints, DeviceSchedule, Device)


# This will raise an AssertionError (due to float being cast to int)
# AssertionError: Broken expectation.
#         Constraint: org.jpyinterpreter.user.__main__/Technician capacity (hard constraint)
#   Expected penalty but there was none.
# 
#   Explanation of score (0hard/0soft):
#     Constraint matches:
#         0: constraint (Technician capacity (hard constraint)) has 0 matches:
#     Indictments:
tech = Technician(id=0, rbh_to_plan=0.1, ...)
(constraint_verifier.verify_that(technician_capacity_hard)
     .given(Device(index=0, rbh_norm=0.1, technician=tech, ...),
            Device(index=1, rbh_norm=0.1, technician=tech, ...))
     .penalizes()
 )

# This assertion would pass
tech = Technician(id=0, rbh_to_plan=1, ...)
(constraint_verifier.verify_that(technician_capacity_hard)
     .given(Device(index=0, rbh_norm=1, technician=tech, ...),
            Device(index=1, rbh_norm=1, technician=tech, ...))
     .penalizes()
 )

This allows you to verify the constraint works correctly.
Unfortunately, you cannot use a Python debugger to debug constraints, since
they are evaluated in Java. The way to debug it would probably be to add a no-op filter that prints its arguments:
def debug(*args):
    print(args)
    return True


def technician_capacity_hard(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (constraint_factory
            .for_each(Device)
            .filter(lambda device: device.technician is not None)
            .group_by(lambda device: device.technician, ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda device: device.rbh_norm))
            .filter(lambda a, b: debug(a, b))
            .filter(lambda technician, total_rbh_norm: total_rbh_norm > technician.rbh_to_plan)
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .as_constraint("Technician capacity (hard constraint)"))

